# QMDI SubWindows switching

Tags: qt, pointers, tabs, signals, qmdiarea

I have an MDI application, with classes as

```
class MainWindow
{     GraphicsView *gv; };
class GraphicsView
{     Scene *scene; };
class Scene
```

I'm creating a new mdiSubWindow on every `newfile()` of `MainWindow` which creates a new pointer to the GraphicsView.

```
void MainWindow::newFile()
{
    gv = new GraphicsView;
    QMdiSubWindow *w = mdiArea->addSubWindow(gv);
    mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(w);
}
```

And the constructor of `GraphicsView` creates a new Scene.

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView()
{
    scene = new Scene;
    setScene(scene);
}
```

Now when there are multiple subWindows created, I lose the ability to work in previous subWindows. Only the latest subWindow works as expected. For eg. I can draw `QGraphicsItems` only in the latest Sub Windows and not in the previous ones.

I think I should be using `activeSubWindow()` but couldn't figure out how to make every subWindow respond to the change of the tabs. How should I implement this?

Comment: What does it mean `"I lose the ability to work in previous subWindows"`?

Comment: @vahancho I edited and gave an example.

Comment: I think you use the pointer to the graphics scene and update it on new view creation. You need to update it when you activate a sub window too. Consider using `QMdiArea::subWindowActivated()` signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work.

I've created a `QList<QPair>`, for storing a pair of subwindow and view.

```
windowViewList.append(qMakePair(w, view));
```

Then `subWindowActivated()` signal is used to call the following function to update the view pointer.

```
void MainWindow::updatePointers()
{
  QMdiSubWindow *m = mdiArea->activeSubWindow();
  foreach (windowViewPair v, windowViewList)
  {
   if (m == v.first)
       gv = v.second;
  }
}
```